# PHP colour recognition script returns wrong colour

Tags: php, function, colors

Ive got a problem with this script that i dont understand.

As far as i can see everything is correct. The script does work, even in a loop and returns colours as expected.

The problem is the colours being output are incorrect...

I've removed the function that scans the image and returns the colour array, and just used a preset green as a test. The script thinks it's closer to red, even though the green value is the same!

Work out the smallest colour difference for that block:

```
function getColor($rgb)
{

$colors = array(BLUE =>0x0a9ef3, RED => 0xea0a2f, GREEN => 0x336633);

$largestDiff = 0;
$closestColor = "";
foreach ($colors as $name => $rgbColor)
{
    if (!isset($smallestDiff)) {

        $smallestDiff = colorDiff($rgbColor,$rgb);
        $closestColor = $name;

    } else if (colorDiff($rgbColor,$rgb) < $smallestDiff)
    {
        $smallestDiff = colorDiff($rgbColor,$rgb);
        $closestColor = $name;
    }

}
return $closestColor;

}

function colorDiff($rgb1,$rgb2)
{
// do the math on each tuple

$red1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,0,2));
$green1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,2,2));
$blue1 = hexdec(substr($rgb1,4,2));

$red2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,0,2));
$green2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,2,2));
$blue2 = hexdec(substr($rgb2,4,2));

return abs($red1 - $red2) + abs($green1 - $green2) + abs($blue1 - $blue2) ;


}
```

Run the scripts using green as a test (normally in loop)

```
$color = '336633';
$closestmatch = getColor("0x".$color);
```

Output is RED! Help!

Is this a problem in the colorDIFF function?

Comment: `Ive got a problem with this script that i dont understand.` *sigh*

Comment: Excuse me? Speak your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$closestmatch = getColor($color);` instead of `$closestmatch = getColor("0x".$color);`

```
$color = '336633';
echo getColor($color); // GREEN
```

Comment: It initially did work, but after changing the input colour t 'ea0a2f' I'm returning Blue when it should exactly equal red!